# How important are the survey weights?

Tags: regression, logistic, weighted-data, survey-weights

I run logit model with a cross-sectional dataset of Indian individuals. I am using descriptive statistics of the same dataset to justify and interpret the estimations of logit model. However, I must report the descriptive statistics with sampling weights in the analysis. Using sampling weight creates big changes in the dataset and nullifies the findings of logit model. Rule says that I must use weight for reporting descriptive statistics. 
Another side, I cannot use weighted logit model as it gives spurious results by inflating the total observations from 1 million to 1.6 billion. I will be grateful if you suggest some solution.

Answer (score 7):

It is imperative that you use sample weights to obtain accurate estimates of  your population under study.  This is especially true if the survey you are analyzing is a complex sample survey where unequal probabilities of selection were used when drawing the sample.  The entire purpose of weights are to allow your results to more accurately reflect the characterizes of the population you are studying and about which you want to make inferences.  If you fail to take the weights into account, then what you'll be reporting are characteristics of the sample and not the population itself.  The characteristics of the population, which is unknown, rather than the characteristics of the sample, is nearly always what survey statisticians are interested in obtaining (outside of methodological-type analyses).

You indicated that you are using descriptive statistics of the same dataset to justify and interpret the estimations of your logit model.  However, you didn't tell us whether or not your descriptive statistics were weighted as well. One simple solution to the issue you seem to be encountering, where you're descriptive analyses are mis-guiding your modeling efforts, is to properly weight your descriptive analyses. Otherwise, your unweighted descriptives are informing your modeling efforts in potentially the wrong directions as you'll be honing in on characteristics of the sample rather than the population.

You also indicated that the application of the weights led to "big changes" in the dataset.  Weights shouldn't not be changing your **dataset**, but the application of the weights should likely be changing the **results** of your analysis form that dataset.  It is no surprise that application of weights changed the results of your analyses compared to analyses carried out without weighting.  This suggests that the sample is somehow represented differently  from the population as a whole.  This happens, for example, when certain groups in your survey are under-represented or over-represented compared to the population in general.  The weights fix this representation problem to make the results from your sample look like the population.  For example, if you oversampled blacks in your survey at a rate 10 times greater than whites, then your weights for blacks would be 1/10 and the weight for whites would be 1.  If you didn't take this into account, then the 10 times more blacks that are contributing responses to your survey would not be taken into account in your analysis, skewing your results to then over-represent black responses.

I'm not sure what you mean by the weighting "nullifying" the findings of the logit model?  Do you mean that when you weight the analyses, the results from your logit model change or no longer become statistically significant compared to your unweighted analysis?  If this is the case, then again, this is because you initially incorrectly approached the analysis or were guided by an unweighted descriptive analysis.  You should not worry if the results do not reflect that you were "hoping for" as the mindful statistician should establish a (null) hypothesis, and then properly carry out the analysis to find evidence either in support or against the hypothesis.

You mention that you can't use a weighted logit model because it gives "spurious results by inflating the total observations from 1 million to 1.6 billion."  Can you help us understand what makes you think this is spurious? When you apply the weights, you **should** be getting larger population estimates.  If you have properly developed your weights and correctly carried out your analysis, your logit model should be reflecting the population characteristics and your model population totals should not exceed the actual population control totals (they should be equal).  To verify that your weights were correctly computed, you should sum all of the weights in your dataset.  The sum should be equal to the total found in the actual population from which you drew the sample. This could also be carried out for any stratification variables used in the design of your sample survey.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you want to use sample weights if your analysis is supposed to be representative for the whole population. Whether the estimates please you should not be  a factor. The fact that you have an Indian population of 1.6 billion (actual: 1.4 billion) suggests that either

- sample weights are specified incorrectly by the data supplied or
- you aren't using them correctly

Either way, if descriptives are with sample weights, the regression should be with sample weights as well. The fact that you have 1.6 billion weighted observations is a natural consequence from this.

More on the use of sample weights: [Solon et al (2015): What are we weighting for?](http://jhr.uwpress.org/content/50/2/301.short)